# 'org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException's; no record information is available

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, apache-kafka

I have springboot application where i am trying to connect to kafka cluster over ssl but unable to connect

getting the below  error

```
ERROR [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.c.l.LogAccessor: Consumer exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException's; no record information is available    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:151)
```

please find below configuration

```
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-type=jks
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/var/ssl/private/client.truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-password=****
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:/var/ssl/private/client.keystore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-password=****
spring.kafka.ssl.key-password=****
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SSL
```

I am using it for both consumer and producer
Tried with lot of possibilities but getting the same error please help

Comment: Hi, what is the solution for this ?. can you please share it @Akshay Ubale